# powershell function returning an instance of user defined class will cause returning a new another instance by constructor

Tags: powershell, class, constructor, return, powershell-5.0

## Environment Info:

```sh
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem


SystemDirectory : C:\Windows\system32
Organization    :
BuildNumber     : 9600
RegisteredUser  : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SerialNumber    : xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
Version         : 6.3.9600 # Windows 8.1, Update 1



PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1018
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1018
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

## Background:

### why I made this:

- my USB HDD is a little bit unstable. and I need to find files and store paths progressively.
- if some error will occur, store the error information instead of the path.
- I intend to use `[TreeElement]` objects for storing and searching.

I made a simple tree class:

```sh
# need Powershell v5.0 higher
class TreeElement
{
    $Value = $null
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[TreeElement]] $Children = [System.Collections.Generic.List[TreeElement]]::new()
    [TreeElement] $Parent = $null

    TreeElement($Value)
    {
        $this.Value = $Value
    }

    [TreeElement] AddChild([TreeElement] $Child)
    {
        $this.Children.Add($Child)
        return $Child
    }

    [TreeElement] AddChildValue($ChildValue)
    {
        $Child = [TreeElement]::new($ChildValue)
        $this.Children.Add($Child)
        return $Child
    }
}
```

I finished coding, and tested like this:

```sh
$root = [TreeElement]::new(1)
$root.AddChildValue(2)
$root.AddChildValue(3)
$root.AddChildValue(4)
$root.AddChildValue(5)

$root
```

The last line will show this in the console.

```sh
Value Children                                             Parent
----- --------                                             ------
    1 {TreeElement, TreeElement, TreeElement, TreeElement}
```

nop.

I wanted to store `$root` to a file.

so I decided to use `*-Clixml`, and coded:

```sh
Function Store-Tree
{
    [OutputType([void])]
    Param
    (
        [string]$Path,
        [TreeElement]$RootElement
    )

    Export-Clixml -Path $Path -InputObject $RootElement
}

Function Restore-Tree
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$Path
    )

    # restore from xml
    $obj = Import-Clixml -Path $Path

    # Reconstruct instances...
    $result = Reconstruct-Tree -RootObject $obj
    return $result
}

Function Reconstruct-Tree
{
    [OutputType([TreeElement])]
    Param
    (
        [PSObject] $RootObject
    )

    $root = [TreeElement]::new($RootObject.Value)

    foreach($ChildObject in $RootObject.Children)
    {
        [TreeElement] $branch = Reconstruct-Tree $ChildObject
        [void] $root.AddChild($branch)
    }

    return $root
}
```

Then I tested it:

```sh
PS> mkdir C:\temp
PS> $path = "C:\temp\root-tree.xml"
PS> $root # original instance

Value Children                                             Parent
----- --------                                             ------
    1 {TreeElement, TreeElement, TreeElement, TreeElement}


PS> Store-Tree -Path $path -RootElement $root # store in xml. instances are converted to [PsObject] internally.
PS> $root_r = Restore-Tree -Path $path # restore instances with type of [TreeElement].

Value       Children Parent
-----       -------- ------
TreeElement {}                      # what?
```

## Problem:

I expected `$root_r` has an instance almost the same as `$root`.

but `$root_r` has an expected object in the Children member.

I wanted to return just the object.

debugging showed that the `[TreeElement]` constructor was running when the function `Reconstruct-Tree` returned the object.

## Question:

Is there a way to return just the object? Did I do something wrong?

I googled some site, but no information was gained.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

self resolved.

## Debug Step1:

- Paste code *[A]* and *[S]* at first.
- Then test with *[T]*.
- Nothing strange.

## Debug Step2:

- Paste code *[A]* and *[S]* at first.
- Then I modified the class `[TreeElement]` like *[A modified]*.
- Paste code *[A modified]*.
- And, test with *[T]*.
- Something strange happened.

## Why?

- (1) When I run the '*[A modified]*', it will fix the definition of `[TreeElement]` itself.
- (2) But the definiton of '**[TreeElement]**' in the function `Reconstruct-Tree` is **not fixed**.
- (3) So `[TreeElement]` of (1) is a different type from '**[TreeElement]**' of (2).
- (4) Then `Reconstruct-Tree` try to return an instance of `[TreeElment]` with the old [TreeElement] type ('**[TreeElement]**').
- (5) And powershell decide the instance is an argument of the constructor of '**[TreeElement]**'.

Sorry for bothering you.
Thanks.

## Sample Code:

### *[A]* : a definition of [TreeElement] class.

```sh
# need Powershell v5.0 higher
class TreeElement
{
    $Value = $null
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[TreeElement]] $Children = [System.Collections.Generic.List[TreeElement]]::new()
    [TreeElement] $Parent = $null

    TreeElement($Value)
    {
        $this.Value = $Value
    }

    [TreeElement] AddChild([TreeElement] $Child)
    {
        $this.Children.Add($Child)
        return $Child
    }

    [TreeElement] AddChildValue($ChildValue)
    {
        $Child = [TreeElement]::new($ChildValue)
        $this.Children.Add($Child)
        return $Child
    }
}
```

### *[A modified]* : a new definition of [TreeElement] class.

```sh
class TreeElement
{
    $Value = $null
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[TreeElement]] $Children = [System.Collections.Generic.List[TreeElement]]::new()
    [TreeElement] $Parent = $null
    [string] $Dummy = "editted class type!"

    TreeElement($Value)
    {
        $this.Value = $Value
    }

    [TreeElement] AddChild([TreeElement] $Child)
    {
        $this.Children.Add($Child)
        return $Child
    }

    [TreeElement] AddChildValue($ChildValue)
    {
        $Child = [TreeElement]::new($ChildValue)
        $this.Children.Add($Child)
        return $Child
    }
}
```

### *[S]* : storing an instance of the class ([TreeElement]).

```sh
Function Store-Tree
{
    [OutputType([void])]
    Param
    (
        [string]$Path,
        [TreeElement]$RootElement
    )

    Export-Clixml -Path $Path -InputObject $RootElement
}

Function Restore-Tree
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$Path
    )

    # restore from xml
    $obj = Import-Clixml -Path $Path

    # Reconstruct instances...
    $result = Reconstruct-Tree -RootObject $obj
    return $result
}

Function Reconstruct-Tree
{
    [OutputType([TreeElement])]
    Param
    (
        [PSObject] $RootObject
    )

    $root = [TreeElement]::new($RootObject.Value)

    foreach($ChildObject in $RootObject.Children)
    {
        [TreeElement] $branch = Reconstruct-Tree $ChildObject
        [void] $root.AddChild($branch)
    }

    return $root
}
```

### *[T]* : Test Code.

```sh
$path = "C:\temp\root-tree.xml"

$root = [TreeElement]::new(1)
$root.AddChildValue(2)
$root.AddChildValue(3)
$root.AddChildValue(4)
$root.AddChildValue(5)

$root # original instance

Store-Tree -Path $path -RootElement $root # store in xml. instances are converted to [PsObject] internally.

$root_r = Restore-Tree -Path $path # restore instances with type of [TreeElement].
$root_r
```